# Multiselect values not posted in HTML email template

Tags: php

I have built an HTML email template but  my Multiselect values are not displaying in  email sent to the user.

the code

```
<p><strong>Hotels : </strong>{hotels-group}</p>
```

`hotels-group` is a multiselect on my form . Although the values are getting posted if I don't use the html template for the emailing purpose
The form looks like  -

```
$form->addOption('hotels-group[]', 'hotel-5', 'hotel-4', 'option 3');
$form->addOption('hotels-group[]', 'hotel-6', 'hotel-6', 'option 3');
$form->addSelect('hotels-group[]', 'Hotels : ', 'class=selectpicker,multiple=multiple, data-max-options=2, data-live-search=true,title=Choose Hotels,data-width=fit,required=required');
```

Any suggestion how I can solve it?

I have tried changing the value inside curly braces to

```
<p><strong>Hotels : </strong>{hotels-group[]}</p>
```

but no effect even tried accessing it as an array ..but no result.

Edit : I forgot to mention , I am using Bootstrap Select plugin .
Edit 2: Generated html code as requested:

```html
<div style="width: 219px;" class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick form-control dropup">
  <button title="Neelesh Inn, Lake Inn" data-id="hotels-group" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Neelesh Inn, Lake Inn</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div style="min-width: 0px; max-height: 169.517px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 48px;" class="dropdown-menu open">
    <div class="bs-searchbox">
      <input class="input-block-level form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    </div>
    <ul style="max-height: 109.517px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;" class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
      <li class="selected" data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Neelesh Inn</span>"><span class="text">Neelesh Inn</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="selected" data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Lake Inn</span>"><span class="text">Lake Inn</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="" data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Royal Rosette</span>"><span class="text">Royal Rosette</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `$form->addMultiSelect()` instead.

Comment: @DishaV. I am using multiselect , and even get the data from the form in the email, but when I use html template , it just shows the variable inside curly brackets i.e {hotels-group[]}

Comment: Could you show us the generated HTML?